# How to normalize value of y axis of multiple linecharts in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

As title, I found the value of y axis in each line chart has large difference.

Is there some way to auto fit(or normalize) multiple line charts with smaller range of y axis?

Answer (score 0):

Gnuplot automatically sets range on axes so that all points are visible and the space is not 'wasted', so it's like a minimal span required to show all the points. If you want to manually set range for axes, you should type `set xrange [min:max]` (substitute numbers for min, max) and analogously with `y`. If you want to return to the default behavior, type `unset xrange`.